# How to reference array that contains arrays in c?

Tags: c, arrays

```
    // test 1
    int aaa[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};

    int *temp_aaa = aaa;


    for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
        printf("%d\n", temp_aaa[i]);


    exit(0);


    // test 2
    int bbb[5][2] = {{1,2},{3,4},{5,6},{7,8},{9,10}};

    int *temp_bbb = bbb; // error
```

For test 1, *temp_aaa can reference array aaa[5]

How to reference a array that contains arrays in test 2 to print out each element?

Comment: `int (*temp_bbb)[2];`

Comment: [C gibberish ↔ English](http://cdecl.org/?q=int+%28*temp_bbb%29%5B2%5D) may be useful.